# Understanding the kehati on Beitza 2:10

Tags: tractate-beitza, zav-zava

Beitza 2:10:

> עֲגָלָה שֶׁל קָטָן טְמֵאָה מִדְרָס וְנִטֶּלֶת בְּשַׁבָּת, וְאֵינָהּ נִגְרֶרֶת אֶלָּא עַל גַּבֵּי כֵלִים. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר, כָּל הַכֵּלִים אֵין נִגְרָרִין חוּץ מִן הָעֲגָלָה, מִפְּנֵי שֶׁהִיא כוֹבֶשֶׁת:
>
> A child’s cart is susceptible to the impurity of midras, and it may be handled on Shabbat, and it is dragged along only on matting. Rabbi Judah says: no vessels may be dragged along [the ground] except a wagon because it [only] presses [the earth] down.

Kehati explains what a “child’s cart” is:

> עגלה של קטן- העשויה לו כדי שילמד ללכת, והקטן נשען עליה והיא מתגלגלת לפניו.
> A child’s cart- that is made to teach him to walk, and the child leans on it and it rolls before him.

So our mishna is talking about a very young child- one that can’t even walk unaided.

Kehati also explains how the cart would become tamei:

> טמאה מדרס- אם הקטן היה זב, הריהו מטמא את העגלה טומאת מדרס...
>
> susceptible to the impurity of midras- if the child was a zav, he makes the cart tamei midras...

How can a young kid be a zav? Isn’t that medically impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A boy can become impure as a zav from one day old, and a girl from ten days old ([Nidda 5:3](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Niddah.5.3)). I don't know about the medical aspect, but the Talmud ([Nidda 32a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Niddah.32a.12)) does mention cases of a baby girl seeing blood, which implies that she could become a zava, and if she were a zava she would be equally capable of making the cart impure in the case of the Mishna in Chagiga.

Comment: Medically speaking, at least for newborn females, it's quite common to initially have some uterine discharge because of dropping hormone levels now that baby is no longer "sharing" blood with mom.